# not able to activate the python virtual env vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have my python `3.8` and `3.7` installed on my system. `Python3.8` as active by default. Now I had created the python venv using following command with `python3.7`

```
virtualenv --python=C:\Users\sgarg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe env37
```

and it created the the new virtual environment with python 3.7.

Now all of sudden when I try to activate this env in vscode, it does not activate this environment. But it shows (env37) in the terminal.

If I check the python version inside the `env37/Scripts/python.exe` it shows the version `3.7`, but outside this directory it shows version `3.8`.

I checked the `env37/pyenv.cfg` it shows

```
home = C:\Users\sgarg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.7.0.final.0
virtualenv = 20.4.2
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = C:\Users\sgarg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
base-exec-prefix = C:\Users\sgarg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
base-executable = C:\Users\sgarg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```

I tried selecting the manual interpreter by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + P`, then browsed the path of /env/Scripts/python.exe

that did not work even.

I tried creating new environment, for that everything is working fine. But what is the issue with existing environment?

Comment: Why have you installed two versions of Python anyway?

Comment: You created a venv with Python 3.7, and this venv uses Python 3.7, right ? Where is the problem ?

Comment: @Metapod yes, even it was working, all of sudden this stopped working, what could be the issue?

Comment: What do you mean it stopped working ? Like the Python interpreter is not the good one anymore ?

Comment: @Metapod, it is not activating it

Comment: Then try Ctrl + Maj + P => Python: Select Interpreter, and then look for the interpreter of the venv, in its folder

Comment: @Metapod tried that too, but did not work

Comment: Weird ... Don't know then, sorry